# Error after importing file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm following Udemy videos and this error is showing up even after importing the header file. The guy in video also gets the error but that was before importing the header file.

[image]

**Edit**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TADFoodTableViewController.h"

@interface TADAddFoodViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,weak) TADFoodTableViewController *foodTableViewController;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *foodTextField;
- (IBAction)addFoodButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

Comment: Show your code please where did you import ?

Comment: 1. Check with library, which  is proper imported?.
2. And the declaration using @property ?

Comment: @MukeshChaudhary any suggestions?

Comment: @Rishab Check your "TADFoodTableViewController.h" it is exits or not. Its only happening due to "TADFoodTableViewController.h".

Comment: @MukeshChaudhary Well of course it exists. I'm getting auto-complete during importing, and auto-complete during declaration as a property. But compilation is failing as you can see in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

You have sucked in import cycle. When we import file 1 in file 2 and try to import file 2 in file 1 then, such errors occur. Try using

```
@class TADFoodTableViewController.h;
```

or import it in .m

Comment: Crap. That's what I did. Why the video guy isn't getting any error then? That's not fair.

Answer (score -1):

i think you should be take (strong,nonatomic) may be will work.